# Associate Deans' power

Tags: ethics, syllabus

If a student complains to the associate dean about an adjunct faculty member, does the dean have the power to intervene?  In this case, the student is complaining because the faculty member won't accept late work, although the syllabus states that this is so.   Can the associate dean override the syllabus and force the faculty member to accept the late work?

Comment: The power and responsibilities of deans etc. vary very strongly from country to country (and sometimes even within a country there might be different regulations). Please clarify this point.

Comment: Which question do you want answered? The Dean's power or the Associate Dean's power or late homework acceptance?

Comment: As was already pointed out, the answer to your question varies a lot. My impression is that at my institution, if a student complained to the associate dean in a situation like the one you described, the associate dean would simply refer the matter to the department chair. In a large department like mine, the chair would refer the matter to an associate chair. So the student might as well complain to the associate chair in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is unclear.  Does the syllabus say that late homework will not be accepted?  Does it say that late homework will be accepted (until when? for what acceptable reasons?  with a penalty?)  You also have not described why the homework was not turned in on time.

As a general rule, as long as policies, procedures, and other rules are being followed consistently and fairly, higher-ups tend not to intervene.  It's unlikely that a dean would intervene to overturn the decision of a faculty member to not accept late homework when the syllabus specifies that late homework will not be accepted.

It's possible that if there are unusual extenuating circumstances (e.g. the student was hospitalized after a car wreck and missed the deadline), and the faculty member is unreasonably insisting on applying the rule without considering those circumstances, then the dean might intervene.

On the other hand, if the syllabus said that late homework would be accepted (perhaps with some defined penalty) and the faculty member refused to follow the policy in the syllabus, then a dean might well intervene.